# Document.importNode VS Node.cloneNode (real example)

Tags: javascript, html, dom, w3c

[Document.importNode in specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#dom-document-importnode)

[Node.cloneNode in specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#concept-node-clone)

This two methods work equally. Please give me real example in which I can see the difference between this methods.

Comment: It's possible that in modern browsers you can't see a difference, (other than they're defined on different interfaces, obviously). Historically, in DOM, importNode was for copying a node from a different document, while cloneNode was for a copy of a node in the same document, but DOM4 does away with the distinction, since the distinction has no useful effects.

Answer (score 32):

Alohci is right: there's not much of a difference, since [web compatibility forced the browsers to implicitly `adoptNode()` before inserting a node into another document](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-dom/2010JulSep/0111.html).

*Before* you insert the cloned node into a new document, there's a difference: the owner document of the node returned by the `cloneNode(original)` is the same as of the original node, and the new document if you call `newDocument.importNode(original)`. You can see this difference if you use `ownerDocument` or related properties (such as baseURI).

But if you call importNode on the same document that the original node belongs to, there's no difference whatsoever.

Answer (score 14):

Simply put:

`element.cloneNode()` is used to clone a node from current `document`, for instance, with shadow DOM when you append any DOM element such as a `template`. There you call `shadowDOM.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true))`, where `template` is an instance of `<template>` defined in your HTML. Here you are telling JS to grab the element from the current DOM and append it to the shadow DOM.

`document.importNode()` is used to clone a node from another document, for instance, with `<iframe>` which has its own DOM, to show any element from an `iframe` into your DOM.

```
var frame = document.getElementsByTagName("IFRAME")[0]
var h = frame.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("H1")[0];
var x = document.importNode(h);
```

`document.adoptNode()` is another method which is quite similar to `importNode()` with a difference that it removes the original element from its parent DOM. `importNode()` copies the original element without removing while `adoptNode()` completely removes the original element from its DOM.

```
var frame = document.getElementsByTagName("IFRAME")[0]
var h = frame.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("H1")[0];
var x = document.adoptNode(h);
```

Comment: I see a lot of code examples online using importNode with template content instead of cloneNode...

Answer (score 6):

I started learning JavaScript a few months ago in my classes and came upon one distinction between those two methods today. Since [Iaroslav Baranov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2702805/iaroslav-baranov) wanted an example, here it is:

I was trying to clone an HTML template tag with its content to create a gallery of books (like a product listing page for an e-commerce website). Here is the HTML code:

```
<template id="modeleLivre">
<article class="livre">
  <header class="titre">${titre}</header>
  <p class="imageCouverture">
    <img src="images/${imageCouverture}">
  </p>
  <p class="auteur">${auteur}</p>
  <p class="prix">${prix} €</p>
  <p class="genre">${genre}</p>
  <input type="button" class="btn_achat" value="Ajouter au panier">
</article>
```

Here is the JS function I tried to run at first:

```
let template = document.getElementById("modeleLivre");

let templateClone;

for (let i = 0; i < gallery.length; i++) {
    templateClone = document.importNode(template.content, true);
    let eBook = templateClone.querySelector(".livre");
    let title = catalogue[i].getTitle();
    let coverImage = catalogue[i].getCoverImage();
    let author = catalogue[i].getAuthor();
    let price = catalogue[i].getPrice();
    let book = eBook.innerHTML;
    
    eBook.innerHTML = book.replace('${titre}', title).replace('${imageCouverture}', coverImage).replace('${auteur}', author).replace('${prix}', price);

    bookListing.appendChild(templateClone);
}
```

This was working flawlessly, but the browser kept searching for an unknown weird image to replace for the coverImage variable:

> GET ../images/$%7BimageCouverture%7D | net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

### The solution

To avoid this error, all I had to do was to switch the first line of the *for loop* - the one using importNode() - by this:

```
templateClone = template.content.cloneNode(true);
```

### The explanation

I have no idea why cloneNode() does not throw an error while importNode() does. My only guess is that importNode() should not be used if the clone reference and the appended clone are in the same DOM.

Anyway, I would be glad if someone could further explain the distinction between the two methods, but since OP asked for an example, here was mine.