# using cloneNode and importNode for appending a child node with templates

Tags: javascript

In an example from MDN Docs, I came across the following code snippet:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  let template = document
    .querySelector("#boxTemplate")
    .content.cloneNode(true);
  let boxID = `box${i + 1}`;
  template.querySelector(".sampleBox").id = boxID;
  wrapper.appendChild(document.importNode(template, true));
  // Irrelevant code
}
```

The corresponding template element within the HTML body is defined as:

```
<template id="boxTemplate">
  <div class="sampleBox">
    <div class="label topLeft"></div>
    <div class="label topRight"></div>
    <div class="label bottomLeft"></div>
    <div class="label bottomRight"></div>
  </div>
</template>
```

My question relates to the following line of code:

`let template = document.querySelector("#boxTemplate").content.cloneNode(true);`

It's apparent that this code already duplicates the content of the template (document fragment). However, I'm curious about the subsequent usage of importNode in this line:

`wrapper.appendChild(document.importNode(template, true));`

I'd like to understand the rationale behind using importNode again in this context, given that the template content has already been copied in the aforementioned line. Can someone clarify the necessity of this additional step?

Comment: You're right, it's unnecessary. This looks like a mistake in the example.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39372886/document-importnode-vs-node-clonenode-real-example